# In Rails how do I display only the value of a hash item within an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm new to ruby/rails and trying to build a simple Projects / Tags app where Projects and Tags are associated as has_and_belongs_to_many to each other. It's basically a simple list of projects that have tags associated, and those tags in turn can be re-used by multiple projects.

I've been loading tags into projects like this:

```
my_project = Project.create(:name => "My Project")
my_tag = Tag.create(:content => "My Tag")
my_project.tags << my_tag
```

All appears well until I try to load the info into my View. I have a list of projects, each with a small table below that lists the associated tags:

```
<table>
 <% @projects.each do |project| %>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td width="300"><%= project.name %></td>
       <td width="100"><%= link_to 'Edit project', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
       <td width="100"><%= link_to 'Nuke project', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><%= project.tags %></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

The View output I get is:

```
[1] My Project               Edit Project      Nuke Project
[2] [#<Tag id: 1, content: "My Tag", created_at: "2012-03-27 19:27:26", updated_at: "2012-03-27 19:27:26">, #<Tag id: 2, content: "My Other Tag", created_at: "2012-03-27 19:41:04", updated_at: "2012-03-27 19:41:04">]
```

In line [2] How do I go about only displaying the values of :content and not the entire hash? Also - is this how I should associate tags with projects?

Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction. Much appreciated!!

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `project.tags` will return an array, so you need to loop over each item and display it. For example try:

```
project.tags.map {|tag| tag.content}.to_sentence
```

Map loops through each tag, and we're displaying the content of each tag, finaly outputting it to a sentence.

There are numerous other ways to do that. Have a look at [the array methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) for more info.

About the other question, has_and_belongs_to_many is fine, but for more flexibility try using has_many :through, as explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). And [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) is the reasoning behind that.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I'll look up has_many :through for my next iteration of this application. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Actually is the map loop you suggested something that I can (or should) move into a model? Or does it make sense to keep it within the view? Still trying to wrap my head around what makes sense within the MVC framework. Thanks again!

Comment: A best practice is to have skinny views, because they're easier to maintain, so you can define a method in the model that returns what you want, and also because this method is directly tied to the model. But if you want the same functionality in the views, but for more than one model, you can just create a helper.

Comment: And to clarify, `map` and `collect`(which are very similar), are not iterators per se. They iterate over the items in the array and return a different array. The `to_sentence` method is a Rails array extension, and it just uses `.join(", ")` and adds a bit more logic to make the output human friendlier. Also, i know lots of tutorials/books say you don't need to know ruby first, because you learn along the way, believe me (i'm a beginner too), you'll learn to use Rails _way_ faster if you learn the basics of ruby first.

Comment: Thanks Shuriu - definitely trying to build up my Ruby knowledge at the same time. Appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rails 3.2, you can use [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) method to extract content only

```
<%= project.tags.pluck(:content).join(",") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm using Rails 3.0, but I'll definitely try the pluck method when I upgrade.